# Prove that $|U|^2=2[\cosh \sqrt{2 m}- \cos \sqrt{2 m}]$

Tags: complex-numbers

How can we prove that $|U|^2=2[\cosh \sqrt{2 m}- \cos \sqrt{2 m}]$ 
When $U=e^{\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}(1+i)}-e^{-\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}(1+i)}$

I expand 
$e^{\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}(1+i)}-e^{-\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}(1+i)}=e^{\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}}‌​[\cos \sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}+i \sin\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}] -e^{-\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}}[\cos \sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}-i \sin\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}]$

$=\cos \sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}[e^{\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}}-e^{-\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}}]+i \sin\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}[e^{\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}}+e^{-\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}}]$
I  don't know the next step from here on.

Comment: You have a mistake: before last exp should be '+' ($(-1)\cdot(-i)=i$).

Answer (score 0):

$|U|^2=U\times U^*$, in which $U^*$ means replacement of $i$ with $-i$.

$|U|^2=U\times U^*=(e^{\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}(1+i)}-e^{-\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}(1+i)})\times (e^{\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}(1-i)}-e^{-\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}(1-i)})= e^{\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}(2)}-e^{\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}(+2i)}-e^{\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}(-2i)}+e^{\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}(-2)}=2[\cosh \sqrt{2 m}- \cos \sqrt{2 m}]$